# Need examples on C++ vector usage

Tags: c++, vector

Given the C++ vector as below:

```
vector<double> weight;
weight.resize(128, 0);
```

Can weight be used as:

```
weight['A'] = 500.98;
weight['P'] = 455.49;
```

What does this mean, and how does one use these values? Could anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 7):

Character literals (like 'A' and 'P') can be automatically converted to integers using their ASCII values.  So 'A' is 65, 'B' is 66, etc.

So your code is the same as:

```
weight[65] = 500.98;
weight[80] = 455.49;
```

The reason you'd ever want to do this is if the weight array has something to do with characters.  If it does, then assigning weights to a character literal makes the code more readable than assigning to an integer.  But it's just for "documentation", the compiler sees it as integers either way.

Comment: Okay, I see, these character literals can be converted to ints

Comment: For counting the number of occurences of ASCII characters (for example prior to compute a Huffman coding tree) it's okay, however changing the character set to hold more than the lower ASCII would invalidate this scheme.

Answer (score 4):

The code is equivalent to:

```
weight[65] = 500.98;
weight[80] = 455.49;
```

Which of course only works if the vector holds at least 81 elements.

Comment: It looks like it holds 128 so we should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should not.
Use `std::map` for that purpose

For example

```
std::map<char,double> Weight;

Weight.insert(std::make_pair('A',500.98)); //include <algorithm>
Weight.insert(std::make_pair('P',455.49));

std::cout<< Weight['A']; //prints 500.98
```

You can also iterate over the `map` using `std::map<char,double>::iterator`

For example

```
std::map<char,double>::iterator i = Weight.begin();
for(; i != Weight.end(); ++i)
  std::cout << "Weight[" << i->first << "] : " << i->second << std::endl;

/*prints 
    Weight['A'] : 500.98
    Weight['P'] : 455.49
*/
```

Comment: @Prasoon, Okay, I will change it

Comment: A character is an integer type so is a valid index into an array (or vector). By changing from a vector to map you are changing the access charastics from O(1) to O(log(n)) not a good trade off.

Comment: @Martin : I never said it was not a valid index. I just said that he/she should not use that because that would indeed be more confusing. Using a `std::map` is cleaner. `you are changing the access charastics from O(1) to O(log(n)) not a good trade off`. That would have a significant impact if n is a very large value. For a small value of `n` and looking at the cleaner syntax of `std::map` I would recommend it. This was not at all a good reason to downvote. You should downvote when the answer is completely wrong or misleading.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: I do consider the answer wrong. And I disagree that using std::map is cleaner to me is seems to complicate things (and complicating a simple concept is a bad trade off). But thanks on the tutorial on how and why to vote.

Comment: @Martin York : You make me laugh. What does your definition of `wrong` say? `But thanks on the tutorial on how and why to vote`. My pleasure.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: Wrong: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=RCK&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&defl=en&q=define:wrong&sa=X&ei=5MJmTPf-EYfksQP1y_WSDQ&ved=0CBUQkAE (as in not correct). You did not answer the asked question and then proceeded to provide something completely unneeded and unasked for. Its an opinion and in the long run we can only see what the community think come back in a day and see what the score is.

Comment: @Martin : So the community is with you. Kudos! :) BTW no offense meant :)

Comment: I'd tend to agree that if the intent is to *map* chars to doubles, a map of some kind would make more sense.  (Though i'd suggest an `unordered_map` instead, if the mapping is incomplete but rather dense.)  A `vector` makes a little sense, but more as a performance optimization than as the way things should be done in general.

Answer (score 1):

So I understand that char literals are turned into Integers. Does C++ support extended ASCII table ?? 
For example if I had a

```
char * blah = 'z'+'z';
```

what would happen ??? 
eg.

```
'z' = 122 in ASCII
```

therefore

```
'z'+'z' = 244  ?? or ??
```

Comment: Try :)
char* blah = 'z';
won't compile, as you are mixing a char ('z') and a char* (blah).
If you use char blah: It depends whether a "char" is a "signed char" or "unsigned char" for your compiler. For mine, it is signed and above math results in -12.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this, you could use a `std::map<char, double>`. Technically, it would also be possible using a `std::vector<double>`, but there'd be all sorts of integral conversions from characters to integers and the program would just be confusing.